# Pros/Cons of using Const in function declarations

Tags: c++, constants

Lets say I have some code shown below that created two vectors and want to pass them to a function and provide assurance the function will not alter the data in the list. Possible locations I've marked with `**const**`. If I miss any please let me know. Basically I want to know if my thinking is correct in terms of each in terms of pros/cons, and the circumstances surrounding when I should use one or the other.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int makeSum(/**/ const /**/ vector<int>& lst) /**/ const /**/
{
    int total {};

    lst.push_back(1);

    for (/**/ const /**/ auto& value : lst) {
        total += value;
    }

    return total;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<int> test1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<int> test2 = {2, 3, 5, 6};

    cout << makeSum(test1) << endl; //15
    cout << makeSum(test2) << endl; //16

    return 0;
}
```

- Const in parameter list: This would allow either a const or non-const vector variable to be passed to this function. However, the variable name lst is referring to an const variable and as such will not be able to alter the data members apart of the vector unless `const_cast` is used on the variable.
- Const after the function declaration: This would require that it was a member function, but would not allow any members to be altered.
- Const in for range based loop: This would force the function to only accept a non-const parameter, but would ensure that the range loop did not alter the reference.

Comment: I stated that in the second bullet point.

Comment: You forgot one thing about passing constant references: Non-constant references can't bind to temporary objects or literal/constant values.

Answer (score 1):

> - Const in parameter list: This would allow either a const or non-const vector variable to be passed to this function. However, the variable name lst is referring to an const variable and as such will not be able to alter the data members apart of the vector unless const_cast is used on the variable.

*"This would allow either a const or non-const ..."* Nope for the latter as long you're going to change it inside that function.

> - Const after the function declaration: This would require that it was a member function, but would not allow any members to be altered.

You don't have a member function actually.

> - Const in for range based loop: This would force the function to only accept a non-const parameter, but would ensure that the range loop did not alter the reference.

*"... but would ensure that the range loop did not alter the reference"*

Of course.

---

[Your code doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08cfe68da03b9b2d) for several reasons:

```
lst.push_back(1);
```

is a non `const` operation applied to a `const` reference parameter.

```
int makeSum(/**/ const /**/ vector<int>& lst) /**/ const /**/
                                                // ^^^^^
```

makes no sense for a free function. The `const` postfix is used for class member functions that can be used with `const` (rvalue) instances of a class.

---

Well, the above explains the technical errors with your code. Regarding the pros and cons about using const the only thing I can say is:

- Use it correct and right away from the beginning.
- Use it to express the intended semantics of your code.

These are on the pro side and make your code more robust against invalid tries to use it.

The con side may come up if you'll need to refactor a bigger existing codebase to get `const` declarations correctly. This can be a serious PITA and should be rethought if that's worth it (especially for already working code).

Comment: i don't think the code was meant to be compiled, simply was an example. Granted he should have nested the `const` class function in a simple class too make this concrete.

Comment: @NowhereMan _"i don't think the code was meant to be compiled"_ I didn't think so either, I'm just trying to explain what exactly fails and why regarding `const` there.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted too make one thing clear first:

> ... unless const_cast is used on the variable.

You should *never* worry about this, and you *certaintly* should not write code to accommodate for such casts. `const_cast` is inherently something dangerous. If you declare something as `const` why on earth would you try and remove that constantness. Their are obviously some cases where the cast may work, but they are rare and far between, and again, should not be a concern of yours when determining if you should declare something `const`.

Here are a few guidelines i follow when deciding to use the keyword `const`

- const member funtions

  -whenever possible, it is good practice to do this to prevent any unintentional changes to the class's members. If you know that the function is `const` than you know for a fact that it will not change any member variables.
- const function paramaters

  -this is way beyond the scope of this question, especially when you introduce overloading,but i will give you some very basic tips.

  -use `const` *by value* when you do not need to actually modify that copied value inside the function at all. An example would be integral values, which are almost always passed by value. If you have, for example `const int x` but never modify `x` make it `const`

  -use `const` *by reference* the same way you use `const` *by value*, the only difference being you will be passing *by reference*  objects that are expensive to copy, like *vector*.
- const range-for loops

  -use `const` when you are not modifying the object, only reading it.

A rule of thumb. Use `const` whenever you are sure that the object will not be modified. If you are not completely sure, don't use it. It's really as simple as that. Hope this helped!